# many to many DTO example with aspbolierplate

Tags: c#, angular, entity-framework, asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

How can I create many-to-many relationship DTO? In other words, I can't find any good example.
I have followed EF Core examples and I have already created two Entity tables and one intermediary table.

The question is: how do I properly create DTO objects for Selecting, Editing, Inserting of these entities, and their relationships.

**Can you please point to an example?**

Thank you!

Edit: *maybe you can point me out to an example in aspnetboilerplate or asp.net zero where many-to-many is implemented/used?*

Comment: You just need to pick one side and work from that side. In ABP look the relation between users and roles. A user can have many roles and a role can be assigned to many users.   The way it works is you can create a User first then assign roles to it. Or you create a role and assign users to it. If you want to do this at one call then it is also possible as you would carry all the information in a single Dto and crate the User first then create the Role and link them together after.

Comment: Hi @akd. Yes I just need to do it from one side. So are you saying that if I choose to have roles saved with a bunch of users my RoleDTO would only need to have a collection of UserDTIs? I'm very new to this. Maybe you can point me to a good example or tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have the following entities: EntityA, EntityB, EntityAB (linking A and B).
You could do the following to insert or update an object of EntityA including related objects of EntityB:

```
EntityACreateUpdateDto
{
   ...
   ICollection<EntityABCreateUpdateDto> BInstances { get; set; } // navigate from A to Bs
}

EntityABCreateUpdateDto
{
   ...
   int AInstanceId { get; set; } // foreign key
   EntityBCreateUpdateDto BInstance { get; set; } // navigate to B instance
}

EntityBCreateUpdateDto
{
   ...
   int ABInstanceId { get; set; } // foreign key
}
```